# Why isn't this function being called properly in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, canvas

I'm trying to test a portion of my program, and the test involves drawing a bunch of lines using Canvas. To do this, I created a JavaScript object called Lines that holds positions and sizes of the lines to be drawn.

I'm not sure I constructed the object properly, or added the .drawLines method properly, but for some reason when I instantiate a new instance of the Lines object and call drawLines(), I receive a TypeError that drawLines() is not a function.

Why is it not able to call this function?

Code below

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

// create object that holds all lines position and sizes
function Lines (numLines = 100) {
    this.numLines = numLines;
    this.positions = function (numLines) {
        var array = []
        for (i = 1; i <= numLines; i++) {
            array.push(i)
        }
        return array
    };
    this.sizes = function (numLines) {
        var array2 = []
        for (i = 1; i <= numLines; i++) {
            array2.push(math.random() * numLines)
        }
        return array2
    };
    

    
}

// create function that draws all lines based on how the object looks 
Lines.drawLines = function () {
    for (i = 1; i <= Lines.positions; i++) {
        console.log("test")
    }
}
var newLines = new Lines(100);
newLines.drawLines()

function drawLine (position, size) {


    ctx.moveTo(position, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(position, size*5);
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you define `Lines.drawLines`, you will only be able to call `Lines.drawLines`. You want to define the function on the [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes), so that the objects created from `Lines` will inherit it:

```js
function Lines() {
  console.log("Created Lines");
}
Lines.prototype.drawLines = function() {  // <-- HERE
  console.log("Lines drawn");
}
const newLines = new Lines();
newLines.drawLines();
```